# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {nco.surt/android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$Status}

Tags: android

i am getting this error when ever i try to click a button:

```
public class NncActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(NncActivity.this, Status.class));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

i have added

```
<activity android:name=".Status"></activity>
```

to the Manifest exactly after the first `</activity>`
but i am still getting that error!

anyone has any idea why?

this is what the Logcat shows

```
> threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {nco.surt/android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$Status}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
at nco.surt.NncActivity$1.onClick(NncActivity.java:23)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `Status.class` you are using in the intent refers to `android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration$Status` instead of your `Status` Activity. Check your `#import`s to see you are not getting the wrong import, or use the qualified name for `Status` in your intent.

Comment: @Waleed Akleh: Yeah, as I already said `Status` refers to `android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration.Status`... are you even using that in your code? Or did the auto-import Eclipse feature got in your way?

Comment: the auto-import Eclipse feature got in my way

Answer (score 0):

This activity is on the same package from your Main Activity? 
If not, add the all extension of the package name. For example, package: br.com.test and your Activity is there, so...

```
<activity android:name="br.com.test.Status"></activity>
```

If the problem persists, try to clean your project.